# как в swift сделать чтобы при нажатии копки она исчезала

Tags: xcode, swift, button, события

Как в swift сделать чтобы при нажатии копки она исчезала, использую 2 swift, не судите строго я новичок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё можно просто поиграться с alpha.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func myButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
myButton.alpha = 0
...
}
```

Comment: ВАШ СОВЕТ САМЫЙ ЛУЧШИЙ ДЛЯ 2 SWIFT

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

```
   @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func myButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        myButton.isHidden = true
    }
```

**Swift 2**

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func myButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        myButton.hidden = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func myButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    myButton.removeFromSuperview()
    ...
}
```

Comment: А почему remove? Может есть Visible свойство или что-то такое? Может нужна ссылка на первоисточник, или хотя бы краткий комментарий к коду.

Answer (score 0):

Много обьектов в SwiftUI имеет свойство 'isHidden'.
Простой пример как писали выше ' myButton.isHidden = true' даёт  значение Bool и когда оно 'true' кнопка исчезнет и не будет активной пока не дать значение 'isHidden = false'. Это очень просто . Есть много  общих свойств  в UI обьектах, почитайте об этом , без них никак (